# Creating a user history API in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, tastypie

I am new to Django, I am using it to build a server where a person can create an account, then add online newspaper articles that they have viewed. I want the user to be able to view all of the articles they have viewed and I want ONLY that user to be able to see it.

Now the database design has gotten my head pretty confused. 
My schema:

```
    User(id, username, password, email)
    Article(is, url, title, etc...)
    History(id, user_id, article_id, last_viewed)
```

I know how to query for specific users history in the shell (History.objects.filter(User=some_user)), but I don't know how to give each user a history field which automatically queries and find their history. Also, do I have to have one big history table that all of the different user's histories are stored in or can I have a different history table per user?

I just want each user to have a history of all of the articles that they have viewed.

Any advice you can give? I have been using tasty pie to create the REST api.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a manytomany field in the User model and add the id of the article to it every time the user views a certain article.

viewed_articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)

And yes, you can definitely have a different history per user.